# Making a batch file that can append text from a website

Tags: batch-file

Im trying to make a batch file which will do the following things:

- Copy IDs from a file
- Paste the IDs onto the end of a URL
- Copy the text from a certain element in the URL
- Paste said text next to the IDs in the original file

However, i'm struggling getting it to copy and paste each id along the list (Especially as there is text around the IDs) and also getting it the find the text on the website and copy/paste it. Could anyone help?

Comment: Step 3 can't be done with native batch. You're going to have to use a third party program like wget or curl to download the web page and then treat it like a text file.

Comment: Please post your code, it will make easier to help you.

Comment: for the url part you can use https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/winhttpjs.bat   - `call winhttpjs.bat https://www.google.bg -saveto con >>some.file`

Comment: Try downloading with `powershell -c "Start-BitsTransfer http://stackoverflow.com r:\dl.html"`. Then parse the file using `for /f`.